# No realizan consultas a DB SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo un proyecto, en la mayoría de ocasiones las consultas se 
   realizan normal y correctamente , pero en 2 ocasiones (una de ellas esta) no 
   realiza la consulta, a demas intento imprimir la consulta y no pasa nada.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","1234","basededatos");

$ID_PERSONA = $_SESSION['ID'];
$Comentario = 
htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['Comentario']));
$ID_POST = htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_GET['ID']));

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO comentariosforo (ID_Persona, ID_Post, 
Comentario) VALUES ('$ID_PERSONA', '$ID_POST', '$Comentario')");


header("Location:http://localhost/Foro/Post.php?ID=$ID_POST");
?>
```

Comment: la columna de id como la declaraste en la base de datos? como primary key y auto incremental?

Comment: si , ademas tengo mas consultas con otras tablas iguales y funcionan

Comment: no deberías entonces estar mencionando el nombre de la columna y darle un valor, ya que tu gestor lo va a hacer por ti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te ha comentado Alfredo si tienes el Id en la base de datos como primary key y autoincrementable no tienes que darle valor, la base de datos lo hará automáticamente.

Si el id de la sesión por ejemplo es 3, lo normal es que ya haya una fila en la tabla con el id 3, por lo que no puedes guardar en la base de datos otra fila con el id 3, ya que el id existe y es primary key y autoincrementable.